# How do you assign an icon to a specific program or window in the panel?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, icons, customization

I am trying to complete an icon theme and I cannot seem to find out how to install custom icons. Rather, there are certain windows that I cannot find the icon names for. All of the others have been fairly straightforward; just copy the icon into the icon theme folder and name it with the name of the program. But I cannot get a few applications to work.

Specifically, **Skype** and **Pidgin** windows and the **Skype** notification icon, as well as my home directories (Documents, Pictures, Music, etc.).

What I want to know is what I should name the icons, or what value being used to grab these icons and how to find that value for a specific program.

I am running **Xubuntu**, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive looking and attempts to do what ***desgua*** suggested, I have found that the **Skype** beta as well as the **Pidgin** windows are hard-coded into the programs and cannot be edited by copying over the icons. I can edit the **Pidgin** notification icon, but not the **Skype** one, and I cannot edit either the **Pidgin** or **Skype** window icons.

Feel free to answer if you have anything to add, but this as far as I have been able to get with it on any theme. Specifically if you know how to change the **Pidgin** window icons, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The icons for Skype should be at:

```
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/16/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/48/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/64/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/22/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/256/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/scalable/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/128/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_dnd.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_connecting.mng
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_away.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_online.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_invisible.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/im-skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_connecting.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_offline.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_not_available.png
~/.icons/theme_name/actions/32/skype_contact_skypeme.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/16/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/16/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/16/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/48/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/48/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/48/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/64/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/64/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/64/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/22/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/22/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/22/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/256/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/256/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/256/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/scalable/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/scalable/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/scalable/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/128/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/128/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/128/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/32/skype.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/32/skype_protocol.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/32/im-bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus.png
```

For Pidgin:

```
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/16/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/48/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/64/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/22/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/256/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/scalable/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/128/pidgin.png
~/.icons/theme_name/apps/32/pidgin.png
```

And for home directories:

```
~/.icons/theme_name/places
```

Comment: Can you provide an example set with all of these files in it, so that I can test it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, check it: http://franksouza183.deviantart.com/art/FS-Icons-Ubuntu-288407674